# Issue with Running Apache Tomcat -XDB

Tags: tomcat, oracle11g, port-number

This is the error I get when I try to run tomcat server "the server localhost:8080 requires a username and a password. the server says: XD". I hav researched and found that it is due to Oracle. Since Oracle has hijacked that portnumber. So I changed my oracle portnumber from 8080 to 3010. But i still get the same error! Installing tomcat again also has not solved the problem!

Comment: How did you change the Oracle port number? Did you check if anything was still listening on port 8080? Does your Tomcat have to be on that port, or can you just change its port number to something that isn't in use?

Answer (score 12):

Oracle XDB services uses the port number 8080. So I suggest you to change the port of tomcat by Editing server.xml. for that go into the {tomcat-installation-dir}/conf and edit following line in server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Just change the Connector port to 8081(or something else other than 8080) and restart tomcat. It should work then.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what was happening with me!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I realized that another service has been run on port 8080. I stopped the service and restarted the tomcat. The issue was resolved.